# Set drawable in AlertDialog with AppCompatCheckedTextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I had created an alert dialog which prompt user to select from a list of country. Im using the AppCompatCheckedTextView setCompundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds to set the flag drawable and the select point. It work perfectly when in a wide screen/the phone is set default display size but when in a small screen/largest display size the icon did not match with what it should(some option even missing)

[image: default display size]
[image: display size = largest]

```
imgViewCountry.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // custom dialog
                    final ArrayList<DOItemValueSet> itemValueSets = new ArrayList<>(countryList.values());
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder
                            = EBDialog.singleChoiceDialog(TemplateActivity.this, itemValueSets, EBApp.getEBResources().getString(R.string.ChooseCountry),
                            countryList.get(viewModel.getCountryCode()).toString());
                    builder.setPositiveButton(EBApp.getEBResources().getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                            updateCountry(itemValueSets.get(lw.getCheckedItemPosition()).getValue());
                            refreshCurrentFragment();
                            refreshUI();
                            dltMainDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                        }
                    });
                    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                            for (int i = 0; i < lw.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                AppCompatCheckedTextView checkedTextView = (AppCompatCheckedTextView) lw.getChildAt(i);
                                checkedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                                        itemValueSets.get(i).getIcon(),
                                        null,
                                        checkedTextView.getCompoundDrawables()[0],
                                        null
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();

                }
            }
    );
```

Im not sure where did i goes wrong from my code? or i should not use this method to create this view?

!Edit - Adding custom dialog code -

```
public static AlertDialog.Builder choiceDialog(Context context, List list, String title, CharSequence currentSelected, boolean[] selectedArr, int mode, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener multiChoiceClickListener) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    if (mode == 1) {
        int selectedIndex = 0;
        CharSequence[] array = new CharSequence[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = list.get(i).toString();
            if (array[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(currentSelected.toString())) {
                selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(array, selectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
    } else if (mode == 2) {
        CharSequence[] array = new CharSequence[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = list.get(i).toString();
        }
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(array, selectedArr, multiChoiceClickListener);
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton(EBApp.getEBResources().getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
    });

    builder.setCustomTitle(getCustomDialogTitle(context, title));
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is trying to set the item views manually; this should be done in the adapter. Please post the code for `EBDialog.singleChoiceDialog()`

Comment: The EBDialog is just customize the title and also the list can be a multiple choice or single choice

Comment: If you are having problems in layout for Alert Dialog. I would suggest you create an activity for the dialog and in the manifest set the theme as `alert dialog`. 
For that you can customise the layout using constraint layout and it would be less of a problem. Handling a custom alert dialog is difficult.

Comment: You should made custom alert dialog with custom list and then set images and text and radio buttons in that custom list